# Load flat file data to SQL - when calling from a job, no or few records commit without error, when running manually from solution, it works

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, flat-file

I'm perplexed and would appreciate any help. My SQL setup works by jobs running throughout the day that will upload flat file information if the flat file exists. This is setup using variables and loops and 90% of the jobs run without issue daily.

About six weeks ago, we changed where our flat files were being saved and this caused issues with the formatting that required me to rewrite many of the flat file managers to ensure all records worked correctly. This has been resolved and works perfectly when I'm running all of these jobs manually through Visual Studio.

Now, when a handful of these packages are called from the SQL job, they either do not write any records, or only write a handful of them, and no error is thrown. When I go back into Visual Studio and run them manually, they work without error.

Details on two of the flat files:

1. SHIPPED.TXT - size: 2.13 MB; 2,342 rows; rows committed when loading from SQL job: 85
2. WIP.TXT - size: 11.3 MB; 29,479 rows; rows committed when loading from SQL job: 11,057

I have tried turning off fast load, reorganizing the order they are called in the SQL jobs, thinning out the SQL jobs when they are called, all to no avail.

I'm stuck. Has anyone ever experienced anything like this before?

Comment: `we changed where our flat files were being saved and this caused issues with the formatting` I think that's where you've reached the wrong conclusion (or perhaps this is a language issue). If WIP.txt went from being found at \\server1\share\wip\wip.txt to \\server2\share\wip\wip.txt the only change required of your SSIS package is to have changed the value of the ConnectionString property in the Flat File Connection Manager. _If_ there was also a change to the *structure* of WIP.txt, then yes you would need to edit the definition of the Flat File to align with new layouts but not path changes

Comment: If everything runs great in Visual Studio and erratic in SQL Agent, _assuming_ you're loading the same file to the same table in **both** cases, then it would appear that the updated packages in your local visual studio environment have not been deployed to the server.

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for the comments - the actual structure did change...long story short, the files were not originally delimited, so trailing spaces were being truncated when saving to the new server. Additionally, it is the same file in both cases and the packages have been deployed to the server.